# window.scroll event fires twice when implemeting scrollspy

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollspy

I have implemented the scrollspy just like this

http://jsfiddle.net/L4Gpq/3/

My problem is window.scroll event hits twice when i click on any og the link.is there anyway i can stop the second event.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {   
    alert('Scroll Happened')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because within your `click()` function, you are also calling:

```
scrollTop: $('#'+id).offset().top
```

...which will animate a scroll within the window. If you can provide us with more details about your question and what you are trying to achieve, we can suggest a way around this.

Comment: i have updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L4Gpq/4/ . like this when you click on our story, the active link wont change since there is not much space to move and active the link  if($(this).scrollTop() >= myArray[i]){
            $('nav a').eq(i).addClass('active');
        }.When ever i am handling such kind of situation i am explicitly setting the active link.because of scroll it activavtes the link and based on scroll, the link is resetted to home(as in fiddle)

Comment: @Hsakarp - I understand what you are trying to achieve now (I hope!). So basically, in my understanding, once I click on 'Our Story', you need that link to go active. But unfortunately, the 'Home' div is still visible since it is so large. Therefore, you will need to add a `setTimeout` to wait for the animation to finish, and to make the link active. I will make a fiddle and update my answer for you.

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be extremely buggy. Is there any chance that you would be open to a solution other than `scrollspy`? I use a better approach in my projects that works very well.

Comment: yes, I am allowed to use apart from scroll spy.but I do wonder how that settime out works.

Comment: Can you provide me with a working example, so when I click on 'My Story' it goes down to that div? If you can give me that, without the active class being applied to the link, I can help you from there.

Comment: Hope this is the one you have asked http://jsfiddle.net/L4Gpq/6/ and without the active class http://jsfiddle.net/L4Gpq/6/